# ActiveX control '6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a C# main windows form which listens to a UDP port for message. Upon receiving the desired message, it will launch another form (video form). This videoform consists of a axWindowsMediaPlayer1 which will play a video.

But whenever it receives the message to launch the video form, it will receive a UDP error "ActiveX control '6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment."

```
    private void initCommunication()
    {
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        try
        {                

            // For receiving messages
            //We are using UDP sockets
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            //Assign the any IP of the machine and listen on port number 
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listeningPort);

            //Bind this address to the server
            serverSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint2);

            IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            //The epSender identifies the incoming clients
            EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;

            //Start receiving data
            serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length,
                SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), epSender);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "UDP Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    #region UDP OnReceive
    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;

            serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epSender);

            //Transform the array of bytes received from the user into an
            //intelligent form of object Data
            Data msgReceived = new Data(byteData);

            switch (msgReceived.strMessage)
            {
                case "1":
                    btnPlayVideo_Click(null,null);
                    break;                    
            }               

            txtLog.Text += msgReceived.strName + " : " + msgReceived.strMessage + "\r\n";
            txtLog.SelectionStart = txtLog.Text.Length;
            txtLog.ScrollToCaret();
            serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender,
                    new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), epSender);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "UDP OnReceive Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

The error is thrown in this line
axWindowsMediaPlayer1 = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();

I have searched online and how do I create a STA?

Answer (score 2):

Add the `[STAThread]` attribute to your `Main` method.

Comment: My main method already has [STAThread] already. By default, the program.cs created by the C# windows form already has it...

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is that the callback for serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom() runs on a threadpool thread.  You probably already got a strong warning about that, it made you set CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false.  That was not a wise thing to do, it just stopped Winforms from telling you were doing it wrong, it didn't stop you from doing it wrong.  Getting harder to interpret exceptions is indeed the outcome.  You were pretty lucky to get one, more typically it kinda works but then make your program fail in random and undiagnosable ways.

You must only call code that affects the UI, like the txtLog.Text assignment, on the main thread.  Creating a new form should also only be done on the main thread.  Use your main form's BeginInvoke() method (or the txtLog.BeginInvoke method) in your OnReceive() callback to get that done.

Comment: but even if I do not update txtLog.Text, the error still occurs.

Comment: Sure, but we can't see what you do in btnPlayVideo_Click().  My crystal ball says: I bet he creates a new form in that code.  Which has an ActiveX control that says "you created me on the wrong thread!!!".  You did.

Comment: Yes, your crystal ball is right! By right that is a button which will launch a videoform with mediaplayer activeX control on it. If I physically do a mouse click, it will work. But it will not work when I do it through the UDP remote call. How should I launch the videoform on the main form thread?

Comment: Asked and answered, use the BeginInvoke() method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx

Comment: private void StartVideoForms()
        {
            v1 = StartVideoForm(s1);
            //v1.Show();
            v2 = StartVideoForm(s2);
            //v2.Show();
        }
        private delegate VideoForm StartVideoFormDelegate(String url);
        private VideoForm StartVideoForm(String url)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {    
                this.BeginInvoke(new StartVideoFormDelegate(StartVideoForm), new object[] { url });

                return null;
            }
            return new VideoForm(url);
        }

Comment: hi, i can't get it to launch 2 forms. can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Set the run the `axWindowsMediaPlayer1`'s thread `ApartmentState` properties is `ApartmentState.STA` like:

```
newThread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
```

better way is read the MSDN.

Hope this help to you.